# MySQL: find records where text column exact one space

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have table with text column and try to get all rows that contains exactly one space in this column but receive all records with different count of spaces:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id int,
    col1 text
);

-- insert one space, 6 spaces, empty string
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, ' '), (2, '      '), (3, '');

-- select records where 1 space
SELECT id, col1,  CONCAT('>', col1, '<')  FROM test WHERE col1 = ' ';

-- got all records
+====+=========+========================+
| id | col1    | CONCAT('>', col1, '<') |
+====+=========+========================+
| 1  |         | > <                    |
+----+---------+------------------------+
| 2  |         | >       <              |
+----+---------+------------------------+
| 3  |         | ><                     |
+----+---------+------------------------+
```

[SQL fiddle here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=bc5dbe74406f3e344b5428ea895be723&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)

Reproduced in MySQL 5.7 and 8.0 and MariaDB 10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id int,
    col1 text
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, ' '), (2, '       '), (3, '');

SELECT id, col1,  CONCAT('>', col1, '<')  FROM test WHERE col1 LIKE ' ';
```

Use like to filter the rows.

Alternatively you can also use LENGTH function to do so but this will also show the records which have other characters except space of length 1.

```
SELECT id, col1,  CONCAT('>', col1, '<')  FROM test WHERE LENGTH(col1) = 1;
```

I really don't know why the WHERE function is not working.
You can refer this for more info [The Surprising Behavior of Trailing Spaces](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/04/surprising-behavior-trailing-spaces/)

Comment: Wow, I success with replace `SELECT id, col1 FROM test WHERE REPLACE(col1, ' ', '.') = '.';` but your solution best.

Comment: This answer would be further improved by an explanation of how it works.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.